# Appengine responses becoming slower?

Tags: google-app-engine

my ajax calls to AppEngine doing some very basic logic (and doing all the actual processing in the background, isolated from the frontend) tend to be at least 200% slower than they used to. Like taking 3 seconds instead of one out of a sudden since a week or so.
I am wondering if you guys had a similar experience or something changed in the meantime I am not aware of, quota wise maybe. I am using the free quota.
Thanks
Zac

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no particular change going on, but we can't be sure. However slow response time can have multiple root causes.

If you have no traffic on your application then you might have zero instance running, therefore when you make your request there is the time for an instance to start up.

If you have a lot of traffic, depending on your configuration the request can take more time. You need to fine tune wether the request waits to be handled by an "overloaded" instance or if another instance should start.

If you use an API maybe there is something wrong with it.

I would suggest you enable [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) in your app, it will show you what takes time in your request: you will definitely see if this is something on your side or not.

Comment: In fact the calls are now, without changing anything, much faster responding (at the moment). I know about the limitations around warming up etc, that is all taken into consideration.